# Ionic 2 import libraries

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to implement [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) with Ionic 2.

I have done the following:

> ```
> npm install crypto-js
> typings install dt~crypto-js --global --save
> ```

My `index.d.ts` now contains:

`/// <reference path="globals/crypto-js/index.d.ts" />`

A `crypto-js` folder has been created under `./typings/global`

I then try the following code:

```
declare var require: any;
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

...

private CryptoJS: any;

    constructor() {
        this.CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
    }

    test() {
       alert(this.CryptoJS);
    }
```

As soon as I try reference `this.CryptoJS` (i.e `alert(this.CryptoJS)`) the app crashes.

I am doing something wrong in the way I import the `crypto-js` libraries. Please can anyone advise?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cryptojs), I run:

> ```
> >npm install --save @types/cryptojs
> npm WARN package.json theWhoZoo@ No repository field.
> npm WARN package.json theWhoZoo@ No README data
> npm WARN package.json theWhoZoo@ No license field.
> @types/cryptojs@3.1.29 node_modules\@types\cryptojs
> ```

How do I import `CryptoJS` in the code?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { LanguageModel } from './languageModel';
import { LocationModel } from './locationModel';
import { JobModel } from './jobModel';
import 'crypto-js';

@Injectable()
export class PersonModel {

    public id: number = null;
    public joiningDate: number = null;
    public lastAccessDate: number = null;
    public userName: string = null;
    public password: string = null;
    public firstName: string = null;
    public lastName: string = null;
    public emailAddress: string = null;
    public locations: LocationModel[] = [];
    public languages: LanguageModel[] = [];
    public time: string = null;
    public avatar: string = null;
    public avatar64: string = null;

    //private CryptoJS: any;
    private SECERET_KEY: string = 'secret key 123';

    public getPasswordEcrypted(): string {
        // Decrypt 
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.password.toString(), this.SECERET_KEY);
        var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        console.log('getPasswordEcrypted', plaintext);
        return plaintext;
    }

    public setPasswordEncrypted(password: string): void {
        // Encrypt 
alert(password);
        console.log('setPasswordEncrypted', password, CryptoJS);
alert(CryptoJS);
        var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, this.SECERET_KEY);
alert(ciphertext);
        console.log('setPasswordEncrypted', password, ciphertext);
        this.password = ciphertext;
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Changing to:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

results in:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Running this:

```
typings install dt~crypto-js --global --save
```

results in no build errors, but at run time when `CryptoJS` is accessed (e.g. `console.log(CryptoJS);`), the app crashes.

Comment: This is supposed to be the way forward:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cryptojs

Comment: Could you pleas tell me from where you are getting the SECRET_KEY? 

    private SECERET_KEY: string = 'secret key 123';

Is it user defined?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-rc-0-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-crypto-js/64936) is the solution for this.

After you install the npm libraries

```
npm install crypto-js @types/cryptojs --save
```

Create a declaration.d.ts file under src and add declaration to the module. This resolves your module undefined issue.

```
declare module 'crypto-js';
```

Within the service class itself add the import CrytoJS from the module like this:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

Now in your code you can reference CryptoJS. For, example:

```
 let obj = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(['abcd', this.config.salt].join(':'), this.config.salt));

console.log(obj);
```

outputs:

```
t2eCyUuZMKRNTRqCW0L5KRvMjWhLV887h1ehjCNSr2c=
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this subject is closed or not and i've just solved the same problem for me, so...

Actually, it seems like you just have to install crytpoJS  with :

```
npm install crypto-js --save
```

And import the precise file/library you want to use with :

```
import { SHA3 } from "crypto-js"; // SHA3 one-way encryption
import { AES } from 'crypto-js'; // For AES encryption/decryption
import { enc } from 'crypto-js'; // For characters encodages types (Utf-8, latin1...)
```

Now  you can use CryptoJs functions by using directly the name of imported library :

```
//AES
let encrypted = AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
let bytes  = AES.decrypt(encrypted.toString(), 'secret key 123');
let decrypted = bytes.toString(enc.Utf8);

//SHA
let hash = SHA3('password', { outputLength: 224 }).toString()
```

Maybe it'll help someone, some day...

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to switch to types because ionic uses @types and not typings.

First of all

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

Should be

```
   import 'crypto-js';
```

In this specific case crypto js is not a proper node module so the import is to the general file

There is also no require in typescript unless you installed it, instead you have import. So this doesn't make sense:

```
this.CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
```

This declares an empty variable of any:

```
private CryptoJS: any;
```

If you translate it to javascript it would look like this:

```
var CryptoJS;
```

So this is basically very much redundant. You already have the variable from the import

In Summary this should be your code:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


class SomeClass{

       test(){
           alert(CryptoJS);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Great explanation. However, I get the following error on the `import` line when building the app:  `ERROR in ./app/pages/model/personModel.ts
(5,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto-js'.`  (I have previously done this: `npm install --save @types/cryptojs`)

Comment: If I run the following:  `typings install dt~crypto-js --global --save`, I get the following build error: `ERROR in ./app/pages/model/personModel.ts
(5,8): error TS1192: Module ''crypto-js'' has no default export.`

Comment: It should be import 'crypto-js'; and not import CryptoJs from 'crypto-js'; I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, if I change it to `import 'crypto-js';`, it builds with no errors, but I have the same issue as before, when I run the app, and as soon as I access `CryptoJS`, theapp crashes.

Comment: I have done the following:  `npm install crypto-js`  and  `npm install --save @types/cryptojs`

Comment: Did you attempt to launch it locally(ionic serve -lc)? To see what is the error. Maybe simply change alert() to console.log()?

Comment: I changed to a `console.log`, with `this.CryptoJS`, but because it crashes when the `console.log` is fired, it is not printed. I will try `ionic serve -lc` now....

Comment: Not this.CryptoJS, just CryptoJS

Comment: `ionic serve -lc` gives nothing in the console, it just crashes (i.e. reloads the app) when `this.CryptoJS` is logged.

Comment: Sorry, I have now removed `private CryptoJS: any;` as you had previously suggested. I missed it.  But now I get a build error:  `ERROR in ./app/pages/model/personModel.ts
(29,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CryptoJS'.` when referencing `CryptoJS`

Comment: I have updated the question above to have my full code